# Filling forms in Salesforce Lightning using console commands in Chrome

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to automate the filling of a form on Salesforce with the Lightning interface and am hoping this can be done by simply entering a series of commands in the browser dev console or similar (I'm not averse to running a JScript or Python script or other if that would be easier).

Basically the form is a series of what appear to be Java fields (text, combo boxes, check boxes, etc.) and when I inspect the various elements I would like to fill in I can see their various identifiers as shown below without any issue.

[image]

Most of the fields have a huge list of event triggers associated with them, such as those below for the above text field.

[image]

So is there some what I can use the console (or JS or Python) to quickly and easily set the text to this field in the same way one might select the field and then type in the text?

Thank you!

Comment: There is always a way. What you are trying to accomplish may inform what the best way is. You don't explain what you are trying to achieve